# How to get a particular tag value using Jdom

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am trying to get a particular value from an XML using Jdom parser.
Below is my xml:

```
<recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      **<id root="1.20.3.01.5.2" extension="a"/>
      <id root="1.2.0.5.1.3.2" extension="b"/>**
      <addr use=""><country></country><state></state><city></city><postalCode></postalCode><streetAddressLine></streetAddressLine></addr>
      <telecom value="" use=""/>
      <telecom value="" use=""/>
      <patient>
      </patient>
      <providerOrganization>
      </providerOrganization>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
```

Now from the above xml i would like to get the 'extension' attribute under the 'ID' tag in (Marked in asterik) which has value "3.2" in it and ignore the id tag which contain "5.2".

I am able to get first value but i need to get the second id tag value.

Below is my java code which gives me the first value of ID's extension:

```
XPathExpression<Attribute> expr = xFactory.compile(xPath, Filters.attribute(), null, defaultNs);
        Attribute attribute = expr.evaluateFirst(document);
        if (attribute != null) {
            return attribute.getValue();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what the actual `xPath` is that you are using, but I would image that an xPath something like:

```
//id[contains(@root, '3.2')]/@extension
```

should do the trick.

For me, I ran it with:

```
    String xPath = "//id[contains(@root, '3.2')]/@extension";

    XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.instance();
    XPathExpression<Attribute> expr = xFactory.compile(xPath, Filters.attribute());
    Attribute attribute = expr.evaluateFirst(document);
    if (attribute != null) {
        System.out.println(attribute.getValue());
    } else {
        System.out.println("foobar");
    }
```

Note that I used `contains(..., ...)`, but the spec has other options for searching the text, see the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions).

Comment: i am using the xpath as  //recordTarget/patientRole/id/@extension   and i am getting xpath from properties file

Answer (score -1):

You could get the extension for one concrete id

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlDomTest {

@Test
public void getSecondIdFromXml() {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_file"));

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

        System.out.println("Extension: " + getExtensionById(doc, xpath, "1.2.0.5.1.3.2"));

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String getExtensionById(Document doc, XPath xpath, String id) {
    String value= null;
    try {
        XPathExpression expr =  xpath.compile("//id[@root='" + id + "']/@extension");
        value= (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}}
```

Comment: @ Sergio - Actually the Id is not concrete, but it will contain '3.2' which i would need to validate and pick the extension for that root.  Above answer of rolfl worked by changing the xpath.